# Regular expression in Automata Theory?

Tags: regular-language, dfa, automata-theory

I have the following language and its regular expression

{w ∈ {a, b}* : w has bab as a prefix, and babaa as a suffix}

**Answer:**

Regular expression = bab(a ∪ b)*babaa ∪ **babaa ∪ bababaa**

**Why bold part is needed?**

Comment: Do you think those strings are part of the language, and do you think the first part of the regular expression accepts them?

Comment: yes first part definitely part of language.. the 2nd part don't look like prefix or suffix

Comment: that's the correct answer though. part of the answer justifies that the prefix and the suffix can overlap. I still don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bab is a prefix of babaa, and babaa is obviously a suffix of itself. Therefore, babaa is a possible string.

babaa is a suffix of bababaa and bab is a prefix of bababaa. Thus, it should also be included.